# Dynamic circular motion increases in energy

Tags: physics, mathematics

I am experimenting with designs for physics engines for which I use particles and fields like magnet fields. In magnet fields you have a thing called Lorentz force `F = q*v x B`. However, the particle increases in velocity and therefore the radius is not constant.

The reason for it is that technically the velocity vector would just rotate, but when you add vectors (velocity + acceleration) it doesn't rotate...

I was wondering how dynamic circular motions are possible. A workaround would be to normalize the velocity vector and control its length, but this would be a case-specific workaround, not a good solution for dynamic physics.
I am using the verlet integrator method.

This is the update method in the electron

```
@Override
    public void update(float interval)
    {
        /* Lorentz force - B-Field testing*/
        Vector3d velocity = (new Vector3d(this.position)).sub(this.prevPosition);
        this.force.set((new Vector3d(0,0,-100)).cross(velocity));
        
        verletStep(this.force.div(this.mass));

        this.age++;
    }
```

This is the verletStep

```
public void verletStep(Vector3d acceleration)
    {
        Vector3d newPos = new Vector3d(this.position);
        newPos.mul(2).sub(this.prevPosition).add(acceleration.mul(PhysicsConstants.dT * PhysicsConstants.dT));

        this.prevPosition.set(this.position);
        this.position.set(newPos);
    }
```

Are there any methods to solve this problem?

Comment: Why would you add vectors acceleration and velocity? They are different types. I think this is possible with close to your method but it's possibly unstable at large timesteps. You haven't included time in your velocity equation so I think it could be unstable without you realising.

Comment: Jay, this looks like pretty conventional Verlet integration to me. The main issue is that this type of numerical integration samples acceleration at just the beginning of the timestep, then advances the simulation as though that acceleration were held constant for the entire step. For something like surface gravity, that's a good approximation. For something like the Lorentz force, it's not - the acceleration is changing continuously as the velocity changes. To get proper energy conservation, you'll need a different integrator. The Physics SE might have some suggestions.

Comment: Alright, I'll look at Physics SE, thanks for your comments.